# Is it possible to find such an angle using only angle chasing?

Tags: geometry, angle

I've been trying to solve some problem and I came down to the following seemingly easy question:

[image: figure]

given two triangles ABC and ABD, and their corresponding angles, how do we find the angle $\angle ACD$ using only angle chasing, I know that it's possible to do that by using coordinate bashing or law of cosine for example, but I was wondering if it's actually possible to do so using only angle chasing, no trigonometry involved.

Comment: No I don't, that only allows you to know the sum $\angle BCD+\angle ADC$

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how that can be done, could you please elaborate more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: It is impossible with only angle chasing. (It may be possible for some limited special cases.)

In general, the angle $∠ACD$ is related to known angles via the sine equation below,

$$\sin (∠ACD )\sin (∠ACD-∠C) = \frac{\sin ( ∠CAD) \sin (∠CBD) \sin (∠DAB)}{\sin (∠B) }$$

For arbitrary triangles ACB and ADB, the above relationship  can not be reduced to just angle additions and subtractions.

——————----------

A well-known geometry problem pertinent to the topic here is the so-called the "hardest easy angle question" below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here a certain case is considered.
 Draw a circle which passes points A, B, and D. Draw a chord from D parallel with AB , it crosses the circle at E.Connect E to D and B. We have:

$\angle BED=\angle DAB$

$\angle AEB=\angle ADB$

Summing these we get:

$\angle AED=\angle BED+\angle AEB=\angle DAB+\angle ADB$

If the position of C is such that ED  and EC are  the bisector of $\angle CDA$ and $\angle CAD$ respectively then in triangle ACD we have:

$\angle AED=\frac{\angle ACD}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Therefore we have:

$\angle DAB+\angle ADB=\frac{\angle ACD}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Or:

$\angle ACD = 2(\angle DAB+\angle ADB)-\pi$

Comment: From your solution it turns out that $\angle ACD$ does not depend on the position of $C$... I suspect something went wrong somewhere...

Comment: @Aretino I suspect this step, which seems to come from nowhere: $\angle AED=\frac{\angle ACD}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}$.